# Binding text to my textblock isn't working

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, binding

Here's the xaml:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Errors}" Grid.Row="3" Foreground="Red"/>
```

Here's the ViewModel code:

```
  private string _errors = "";
 public string Errors
    {
        get { return this._errors; }
        set
        {
            if(_errors != value)
            {
                _errors = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => Errors);
            }
        }
    }
```

and then in some function I change the `_errors` variable

```
  _errors = "Compiler Errors :\r\n";
```

But nothing happens in the TextBlock. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have any binding error in console?

Comment: @Jonas In console? what do you mean?

Comment: Maybe the datacontext of textblock is not set to the viewmodel object

Comment: in the visual studio output window (view > output)

Comment: @Jonas Nothing happens in there, I'm not getting any exception, it just doesn't work.

Comment: I still think the datacontext is not correctly set. Try to print it : <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/> You should see the class name of the datacontext object

Comment: @Jonas Ahh.. it is set, I'm already using other Dependency properties that work on the same viewmodel. Here:             this.DataContext = new ProjectViewModel("ProjectName");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting `_errors` variable directly - so no `RaisePropertyChanged` fired. Try to set value by

```
Errors = = "Compiler Errors :\r\n";
```

Comment: So then, how will my dependecy property will look like?

Comment: @idish Your 'Errors' is not a dependency property. It is just a property which will raise the data changed event when being set. Change the code
`_errors = "Compiler Errors :\r\n";` to `Errors = "Compiler Errors :\r\n";`

Comment: @Colin An example, please?

Comment: @Colin You mean, that property will be automatic property?

Comment: Great article about dependency properties: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140620/WPF-Tutorial-Dependency-Property

Comment: @idish If you use 'Errors =' and the binding has no error, then it means that something is wrong with your RaisePropertyChanged method. Try to simply inherit the INotifiyPropertyChanged interface and try by raising the PropertyChanged event yourself

Answer (score 1):

```
private string _errors = "";
public string Errors
{
    get { return this._errors; }
    set
    {
        if(_errors != value)
        {
            _errors = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Errors");
        }
    }
}
```

set it like this :

```
Errors = "..."
```

I don't know how works the method RaisePropertyChanged, but if the lambda expression ()=>Errors is executed it will return the string contained in _errors and not the name of the property that changed ? So try to give directly the name of the property if the method exists.

Comment: I added a small edit that will help you to understand. I think you were trying to notifiy the property that has the name of the content of you _errors string. Sorry for my english

Comment: I'm sorry but it isn't the problem, I'm still using the same method with the lambada expression, I haven't changed the dependency propery at all.

Comment: @idish Ok, so, what did you change? Only the Errors = "..." ? If yes, this is because when you set a property by calling Errors = "...", the method set of the property is executed, if you just set the variable _errors, it set the variable without calling the set method of Errors and then without notifying the change.

Comment: @idish thank you, but what matter is that you improve. Glad to help.

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I will remove the acceptance of your answer, I don't want to mislead the others, hope you'll understand. I'll still upvote you.